# как исправить? по идей число должно быть отрицательным а код выводит положительным

Tags: python

```
a=2
b=3
w = (b-a)/100 # вычисляем ширину полоски
s = 0 # переменная для накопления площади
x = a+w/2 # начальное значение х
import math
while x<b:
#продолжаем вычисление,пока не дошли до конца отрезка
    s+=w*(math.cos(3*x+5))
    # добавляем к s площадь очередной полоски
    x+=w # переходим к следующей полоске
print(s) # выводим результат
```

Comment: а почему у вас площадь должна быть отрицательной?

Comment: ой спасибо я забыл что я ищу площадь так как обратил внимание на обратный интеграл